# Generating all possible subsets of an array returns a list of empty lists

Tags: python, recursion

```
class Solution(object):
    def subsets(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """

        res = []
        self.backtrack(sorted(nums), 0, [], res)
        return res

    def backtrack(self, nums, idx, subset, res):
        res.append(subset)
        for i in range(idx, len(nums)):
            subset.append(nums[i])
            self.backtrack(nums, i + 1, subset, res)
            subset.pop()
```

Practicing interview right now. I am supposed to generate all subsets given a list.
For example,

```
Input: nums = [1,2,3]
Output:
[
  [3],
  [1],
  [2],
  [1,2,3],
  [1,3],
  [2,3],
  [1,2],
  []
]
```

My solution, however, returns `[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]` and I am not sure why. I tried to draw out my solution and I don't get why the subset is turning into an empty list.

What could be the possible issue?

Comment: Just from a quick glance, you have `subset.pop` call for every `subset.append` call. So seems like your subset lists are going to be empty. Also, I'm confused about why you have it set up as a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common error, you saved the actual pointer to `subset` instead of a copy:

```
res.append(subset)
```

In the end you have a repeated list of the final state of `subset`.  Instead do:

```
res.append(list(subset))
```

to force a copy that won't change on you.

Just FYI, another way we could compose this solution:

```
def subsets(self, numbers):

    def subsets_recursive(numbers, index, subset):
        result = [list(subset)]

        for i in range(index, len(numbers)):
            subset.append(numbers[i])
            result += subsets_recursive(numbers, i + 1, subset)
            subset.pop()

        return result

    return subsets_recursive(sorted(numbers), 0, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools combinations to get the same results:

```
from itertools import combinations
t = [list(combinations(nums, i)) for i in range(4)]
output = [list(j) for k in t for j in k]
#output: [[], [1], [2], [3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```